# mp3 encoding in the frequency domain

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, continuous-signals, frequency-domain, analog-to-digital

Let's start with an arduino signal, which can be periodic over time. When this signal is converted from analog to digital it "turns" into a series of bits. At this point, is this signal in the frequency domain? Why should the FFT be applied?

Comment: I strongly recommend to study a text book about the basics of Digital Signal Processing. You could even begin by checking out Wikipedia, as you seem to lack the most basic knowledge in this field. No offense.

Comment: No offense, indeed thanks for the advice. I am studying these things at school now, so I am not yet very well informed. I asked this question because I thought I was getting more information than wikipedia. Anyway thanks for the advice

Comment: The thought of getting more information here is not wrong per se. But your question ist much to broad. Start studying the basics by yourself, the community here will be happy to answer any specific questions that might arise.

Comment: okay, thanks for the info and advice